# How do I remove noise from a point cloud?

Tags: graphics, 3d, point-clouds

What are the more practical approaches to remove noise from point cloud data? We are looking for white papers or tutorial on the subject.

Comment: This is will depend greatly on what sort of noise your point cloud contains. Small/Large-amplitude? What is the average SNR like? Do you visualize the data using volume rendering (noise tolerant) or poly-based isosurface (looks horrible with noise)? Please provide more information.

Comment: Small noise definitely. The one you get with 3D scanners for example.

Comment: Are you looking to generate a smooth polygonal isosurface from this data?

Comment: I think so, like Poisson or Ball pivoting...